# Mongoid - has_many: parent losing relation to child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following (simplified) relation:

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :description 
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :date
  field :amount
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Now I have the follwing problem: When I update a payment in my controller, the payment data is updated, but the Project "forgets" about the updated element. This is the relevant code from my controller:

```
def update
    respond_with Payment.where(id: params[:id]).update(params[:payment])
end
```

If I go to the console, "payment.project" will return the relevant project, whereas "project.payments" will not show the relevant payment. "payment" still has the relevant "project_id" field with the ID of the project.

Adding and deleting payments to/from a Project works fine, this problem only exists when a payment is edited (the project_id is not changed, only the other fields, eg. amount).

What could be the issue? Is this a problem with my mongoid configuration? Or did I not set up the relation correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and trial and error, I found a solution. The problem was in my controller. Using `update_attributes` instead of `update`, fixes the problem. The relevant part of the controller should therefore read:

```
def update
    respond_with Payment.where(id: params[:id]).first().update_attributes(params[:payment])
end
```

Additionally, the above code was also missing autosave:true for the has_many properties.

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :description 
  has_many :payments, autosave:true
end
```

If someone has an explanation of what exactly was going on, that would be very interesting and helpful for my understanding.